# Cuttlefish.io (Ruby on Rails) configuration for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Default cuttlefish.io configuration (from Git repository https://github.com/mlandauer/cuttlefish) is based on use of a Postgres DB. How to change it to use a MySQL DB?

More specifically:

- What to put in [...]/cuttlefish-master/config/database.yml to switch to MySQL, and specify DB user and password?
- Is there a MySQL adapter to install? How to do it?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `Gemfile` change the lane:

  ```
  gem 'pg'
  ```

  to:

  ```
  gem 'mysql2'
  ```
- Run `bundle install`
- In `config/database.yml` change the lane:

  ```
  adapter: postgresql
  ```

  to:

  ```
  adapter: mysql
  ```

For other configuration options refer to the [official configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: It's all good after installing mysql2, connexion to DB is OK. I can now start the server, but going on http://localhost:3000 gives "this page can not be displayed" error...

Comment: you need to check the log message